# Jquery animate function trying to set height and width

Tags: jquery

Hello I have some problems understading the Jquery API - especially the animate function: This is described in the api:

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
  $('#book').animate({
    width: ['toggle', 'swing'],
    height: ['toggle', 'swing'],
    opacity: 'toggle'
  }, 5000, 'linear', function() {
      $(this).after('<div>Animation complete.</div>');
  });
});
```

Now I want to insert a width value of 100% and a height of 100%...but this is not working...can anyone help me out with the syntax?

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
  $('#book').animate({
    width:'100%'['toggle', 'swing'],
    height:'100%' ['toggle', 'swing'],
    opacity:'toggle'
  }, 5000, 'linear', function() {
      $(this).after('<div>Animation complete.</div>');
  });
});
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried removing `['toggle', 'swing']` part? These arrays are there just to describe possible options that a transformation parameter might take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'100%' ['toggle', 'swing']` is a syntax error.  In the array, the first element tells jQuery how to adjust the value, and the second is the easing function.  If you want to keep the `swing` easing function, you would use

```
width: ['100%', 'swing'],
height: ['100%', 'swing'],
```

Else, if you want to use the default easing, specify only `'100%'`:

```
width: '100%',
height: '100%',
```